# Sending commands to devices in FIWARE Orion is not working

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to provide a device on FIWARE and send commands. In my case, a lamp with commands ("on" and "off"). But, it's not working. 
The steps to create a device and send command are:

1. Provide a device;
2. Create a service group;
3. Create a registration with commands;
4. Send a command.

I'm taking the [fiware-tutorials](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-Agent) following the steps, but don't work.

The code I have used was:

To create a device:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "lamp1",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1",
      "entity_type": "Lamp",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "transport": "HTTP",
      "endpoint": "http://iot-sensors:3001/iot/lamp1",
      "commands": [
        {"name": "on","type": "command"},
        {"name": "off","type": "command"}
       ],
       "attributes": [
        {"object_id": "s", "name": "state", "type":"Text"},
        {"object_id": "l", "name": "luminosity", "type":"Integer"}
       ],
       "static_attributes": [
         {"name":"refStore", "type": "Relationship","value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'
```

To create a service group:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/services' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
 "services": [
   {
     "apikey":      "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
     "cbroker":     "http://orion:1026",
     "entity_type": "Thing",
     "resource":    "/iot/d"
   }
 ]
}'
```

To create a registration for commands:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/registrations' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "description": "Lamp Commands",
  "dataProvided": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1","type": "Lamp"
      }
    ],
    "attrs": [ "on", "off" ]
  },
  "provider": {
    "http": {"url": "http://orion:1026/v2"},
    "legacyForwarding": true
  }
}'
```

To send a "on" command:

```
curl -iX PATCH \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1/attrs' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "on": {
      "type" : "command",
      "value" : ""
  }
}'
```

Doing a HTTP get request to retrieve the entity:

```
curl -G -X GET \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1' \
  -d 'type=Lamp' \
  -d 'options=keyValues' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

I expect a output like:

```
{
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:001",
  "type": "Lamp",
  "TimeInstant": "2019-08-28T13:33:51.00Z",
  "luminosity": "1115",
  "off_info": " ",
  "off_status": "UNKNOWN",
  "on_info": " on OK",
  "on_status": "OK",
  "refStore": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001",
  "state": "ON",
  "on": "",
  "off": ""
}
```

but I receive this:

```
{
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1",
  "type": "Lamp",
  "TimeInstant": "2019-08-28T12:50:22.00Z",
  "luminosity": " ",
  "off_info": " ",
  "off_status": "UNKNOWN",
  "on_info": "There was an error in the response of a device to a command [404]: on NOT OK",
  "on_status": "ERROR",
  "refStore": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001",
  "state": " ",
  "on": "",
  "off": ""
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create the registration, the IOTA will crate it on your behalf upon device registration. Thus, I recommend to reset the test (i.e. drop the CB and IOTA databases) then repeat the tests *without* creating the registration. In fact, at the same point you can read existing registrations with `GET /v2/registrations` as sanity check (you should see the registration corresponding to the commands).

Comment: Btw, which particular IOTA are you using?

Comment: I am using the IoTA for HTTP ultralight 2.0

Comment: I tried your sugestion (i.e. tests without creating registrations), but still the same. when i run  ```GET /v2/registrations```, i get the empty response.

Comment: Try to reserve the order of the first two steps. I mean, first, create the service group. Then, provide the device.

Comment: still not working, i suspect my problem about docker-compose configuration file, i use the file from tutorial. But if i use a differente docker-compose, the message says: ```There was an error in the response of a device to a command []:Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND iot-sensors iot-sensors:3001```

Comment: Yes... it could be. This kind of issues is usually related to connectivity issues. And docker-based networking sometimes is tricky :)

Comment: do you have any tips to help me to configure the docker-compose file ? I mean, the configuration itself, what docker images i need to run commands etc

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't. I'd recommend you to open a specific question in StackOverflow about that. Try to describe the issue in docker terms (I mean, without referring to specific FIWARE components) and label it with "docker ", "docker-networking" and/or "docker-network2. That way you will reach a wider audience so they can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the FIWARE Tutorial Dummy devices, then your provisioning steps are correct and the error message received (**404**) indicates that `lamp1` is not responding to your command when sent.

When you are provisioning the device

```
 "device_id": "lamp1",
 "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1",
 "endpoint": "http://iot-sensors:3001/iot/lamp1",
```

You are stating that:

- There exists a device (`lamp1`)
- The device has an entity name in Orion  (`urn:ngsi-ld:Lamp:1`)
- The device is able to respond to commands on the url shown  (`http://iot-sensors:3001/iot/lamp1`)

The final statement is incorrect.

The [context-provider](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Step-by-Step/blob/master/context-provider/controllers/ultraLight.js#L234-#L237) code sets up 4 dummy lamps:

- `lamp001`
- `lamp002`
- `lamp003`
- `lamp004`

But no `lamp1` - therefore when an HTTP POST request is sent to `http://iot-sensors:3001/iot/lamp1` the response is a **404 Not Found** - which is correctly defined in your entity state in Orion.

BTW, @fgalan is entirely correct in stating that the registration is no longer necessary with  more modern versions of the IoT Agents - it has been left in the tutorial purely for backwards compatibility with older versions.

Comment: Ok. But, in my case, if i need to send commands to a generic device, how do i do this ? If i understand what you've said, the problem is why im using a entity which dont exists on docker tutorial image, right ?

Comment: If you are using HTTP as a transport, the question is at what URL is the actuator listening on? It must be listening somewhere.

Comment: I can post the docker-compose.yml file if you want.

Comment: could you please share the link for "FIWARE Tutorial Dummy devices" ???

Comment: The code for all the tutorials and the dummy context providers (both IoT and the Supermarket app) can be found on the [FIWARE GitHub](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Step-by-Step)